# Prove the statement $\forall x\in\mathbb N (x > 1\to\exists k\in\mathbb N\exists m \in\mathbb N (m \equiv 1 (\text{mod }2) \wedge x = 2^km))$.

Tags: predicate-logic

Can someone please show me how to prove this statement?
$$\forall x\in\mathbb N (x > 1\to\exists k\in\mathbb N\exists m \in\mathbb N (m \equiv 1 (\text{mod }2) \wedge x = 2^km))$$
I can only assume $m = 3$ and when $x > 1$.

Comment: Can you write down, in words, what this means? That may help. If not, I can help you.

Answer (score 1):

The statement uses a lot of unnecessary notation. What it means is

> Every integer $x>1$ can be expressed as an odd natural number multiplied by a power of $2$.

Can you see why this is true?

Hint: what happens if you take the largest power of $2$ that divides $x$? (Note that this might be $2^0=1$.)

Comment: yes but I just don't know how to prove it using mathematical method, I can only prove it using examples.

Comment: Ok, have added a hint.